# Появление ссылок sowi на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Доброго времени суток.

Сайт на WordPress 4.5.13.

При переходе на мобильную версию вверху страницы появляются ссылки, генерируются рандомно. Все ссылки разные, ведут всегда на разные ссылки. После обновления страницы ссылка меняется. Не понимаю откуда они берутся.

С компьютера их не видно, даже в эмуляторе и devtools.

Подскажите как узнать, откуда они берутся, как их убрать. Прилагаю скрин.
Возможно ли что это вирусы или взлом? Хотелось бы избавиться от них.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да у вас jquery грузится с какого-то левого сайта 29wp.org. Дальше можно ничего не смотреть в принципе.

Comment: Если бы ты дал адрес сайта - можно было бы проанализировать. А так пованнгую - тема /плагины с помойки и/или самописные и/или древние.

Comment: @SeVlad ну я специально ссылку оставил dostup-mebel.ru

Comment: @KAGGDesign как он может грузиться с сайта, если он грузится с нашего хостинга?.

Comment: 1. *Ссылки* в вопросе нет. 2. Тема древння, наверняка с помойки. В этом и причина - там дыры, шеллы и тд.

Comment: Вы в dev tools браузера-то посмотрите. Это вам кажется, что он грузится с вашего хостинга: http://take.ms/vxmoL Ваш сайт хакнули, оттого и проблемы.